# sed replace string with pipe and stars

Tags: bash, sed, regexp-replace

I have the following string:

```
|**barak**.version|2001.0132012031539|
```

in file `text.txt`.
I would like to replace it with the following:

```
|**barak**.version|2001.01.2012031541|
```

So I run:

```
sed -i "s/\|\*\*$module\*\*.version\|2001.0132012031539/|**$module**.version|$version/" text.txt
```

but the result is a duplicate instead of replacing:

```
|**barak**.version|2001.01.2012031541|**barak**.version|2001.0132012031539|
```

What am I doing wrong?
Here is the value for module and version:

```
$ echo $module
barak
$ echo $version
2001.01.2012031541
```

Comment: Don't use the `-i` option with `sed` until your script is known to be generating the correct output.  It is insane to overwrite your file until you know the result is (probably) going to be correct,.

Comment: @Cyrus, thanks for the editing.

Comment: @Jonathan Leffler - small command ant it return to previous : $ echo $test > text.txt

Comment: Bad habits hurt when you least expect them to, and when you can least afford them to.  Don't use `-i` on undebugged `sed` scripts if you value your sanity.  (It won't often cost you your job, but it can reach that level if you're not somewhat careful.)

Comment: Cannot Reproduce: when I copy'n'paste your `sed` script and replace `-i` with `-e` (deleting it would also work), I get the expected output from the given input.  `module='barak'` —
`version='2001.01.2012031541'` —
`echo '|**barak**.version|2001.0132012031539|' |` —
`sed -e "s/\|\*\*$module\*\*.version\|2001.0132012031539/|**$module**.version|$version/"` — with the long dashes out of the code blocks representing newlines.

Comment: I tried your suggestion still got a duplication :-(

Comment: maybe it relates to bash version? I'm using git bash for testing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assumptions:

- lines of interest start and end with a pipe (`|`) and have one more pipe somewhere in the middle of the data
- search is based solely on the value of `${module}` existing between the 1st/2nd pipes in the data
- we don't know what else may be between the 1st/2nd pipes
- the version number is the only thing between the 2nd/3rd pipes
- we don't know the version number that we'll be replacing

Sample data:

```
$ module='barak'
$ version='2001.01.2012031541'

$ cat text.txt
 **barak**.version|2001.0132012031539|     <<<=== leave this one alone
|**apple**.version|2001.0132012031539|
|**barak**.version|2001.0132012031539|     <<<=== replace this one
|**chuck**.version|2001.0132012031539|
|**barak**.peanuts|2001.0132012031539|     <<<=== replace this one
```

One `sed` solution with `-E`xtended regex support enabled and making use of a capture group:

```
$ sed -E "s/^(\|[^|]*${module}[^|]*).*/\1|${version}|/" text.txt
```

Where:

- `\|` - first occurrence (escaped pipe) tells `sed` we're dealing with a literal pipe; follow-on pipes will be treated as literal strings
- `^(\|[^|]*${module}[^|]*)` - first capture group that starts at the beginning of the line, starts with a pipe, then some number of non-pipe characters, then the search pattern (`${module}`), then more non-pipe characters (continues up to next pipe character)
- `.*` - matches rest of the line (which we're going to discard)
- `\1|${version}|` - replace line with our first capture group, then a pipe, then the new replacement value (`${version}`), then the final pipe

The above generates:

```
 **barak**.version|2001.0132012031539|
|**apple**.version|2001.0132012031539|
|**barak**.version|2001.01.2012031541|     <<<=== replaced
|**chuck**.version|2001.0132012031539|
|**barak**.peanuts|2001.01.2012031541|     <<<=== replaced
```

Comment: Works like a charm! thank you! BTW - in my case no need for the /g - will need to replace exactly one occurrence.

Answer (score 0):

An awk alternative using GNU awk:

```
awk -v mod="$module" -v vers="$version" -F \| '{ OFS=FS;split($2,map,".");inmod=substr(map[1],3,length(map[1])-4);if (inmod==mod) { $3=vers } }1' file
```

Pass two variables mod and vers to awk using $module and $version. Set the field delimiter to |. Split the second field into array map using the split function and using . as the delimiter. Then strip the leading and ending "**" from the first index of the array to expose the module name as inmod using the substr function. Compare this to the mod variable and if there is a match, change the 3rd delimited field to the variable vers. Print the lines with short hand 1

Answer (score 0):

Pipe is only special when you're using *extended* regular expressions: `sed -E`
There's no reason why you need extended here, stick with basic regex:

```sh
sed "
    # for lines matching module.version
    /|\*\*$module\*\*.version|/ {
        # replace the version
        s/|2001.0132012031539|/|$version|/
    }
" text.txt
```

or as an unreadable one-liner

```sh
sed "/|\*\*$module\*\*.version|/ s/|2001.0132012031539|/|$version|/" text.txt
```

Comment: I tired your suggestion, it seems that it prints the same string: ```sed "/|\*\*$module\*\*.version|/ s/|2001.0132012031539|/|$versionX|/" text.txt
|**barak**.version|2001.01.2012031539|``` BTW why do we need the capital X?

Comment: The X was a typo

Comment: I tried it also without the X, but sill got the same input as a result